# Should I name "makefile" or "Makefile"?

Tags: coding-style, makefile, gnu-make

Although both names will do the job, what is the correct name for makefiles?

[GNU `make' homepage](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) uses *Makefile*, and I guess it is the good way to name it. Any reasons for typing the front *M* in upper case ?

Comment: in practice, it's almost always Makefile

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[What Name to Give Your Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names) chapter of GNU Make manual clarifies it:

> By default, when `make` looks for the makefile, **it tries the following names, in order: `GNUmakefile`, `makefile` and `Makefile`**. Normally you should call your makefile either `makefile` or `Makefile`. (**We recommend `Makefile` because it appears prominently near the beginning of a directory listing**, right near other important files such as `README`.) The first name checked, `GNUmakefile`, is not recommended for most makefiles. You should use this name if you have a makefile that is specific to GNU `make`, and will not be understood by other versions of make. Other make programs look for `makefile` and `Makefile`, but not `GNUmakefile`.

Comment: In response to a now-deleted follow-up comment (incorrectly posted as an answer), the reason you want the Makefile near the top of a directory listing is that it is one of the good starting points for understanding how a project is organized and how all the other files are related to each other.

Answer (score 4):

I think that Makefile is displayed at the almost top of the list rather than makefile when using the `ls` command.

Comment: That depends on your locale setting.

Answer (score -1):

it is not only the reason that it appears prominently near the beginning of a directory listing, but also that it would cause a compile error when you using “makefile” to replace “Makefile”。 you could try to test in the helloworld case of Linux device driver..