# Is the convention for naming make files to use a capital 'm', such as Makefile?

Tags: makefile, capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I name “makefile” or “Makefile”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669367/should-i-name-makefile-or-makefile)

What's the standard convention for make files as far as its capitalization. I've seen both Makefile and makefile. Does it depend on language? Project?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no universal convention.  I prefer "makefile", because it's easier to type!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use either of them, but conventionally `Makefile` is preferred over `makefile`. If you have both `Makefile` and `makefile` in the same directory and you just type `make` then `makefile` is executed and `Makefile` is ignored.

Comment: Why and by who is one preferred over the other? Seeing how `makefile` has priority, shouldn't that be the preferred one then?

Comment: @domsson Right.

Comment: @domsson Makefile is preferred for this reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669367/should-i-name-makefile-or-makefile

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't matter. The make program looks for either one. I personally prefer Makefile since I'm always on Linux and it shows up first in the directory listing since I use lower case on all of my .ccp and .h files.

Comment: This should be of interest: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Names.html. Note that for GNU make if you have a makefile and a Makefile, the Makefile would be ignored. ;)

Comment: Neither `ls` nor `ls -l` arrange by case for me. Although I tried `ls -u`, guessing "uppercase", and `Makefile` then showed up first. I don't think I like `ls -u`, so I'll stick with `makefile` for its "easy-to-type-ness", and if I need to see if a makefile exists, I'll just use `ls | grep akefile`.

Comment: Sorry. I use LC_COLLATE=C instead of the default en_US.utc8. Old unix guy. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is usually capitalized. At least on *nix systems.

Comment: "I believe" indicates this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Makefile` (capitalized) is a standard in Unix world, where file system is case sensitive (i.e.  `makefile`, `MAKEFILE` and `Makefile` are all different files). On Windows, it doesn't matter.